# Creating tabs with CSS only, but some inputs are buried under two divs

Tags: css

I'm only starting out on CSS. My code is basically a list of divs under one div, and a second list of divs under a second div. It's a lot of copy-paste. Look:

```
        <div id="button_container">
        <!--Try and get this to be generated by PHP-->
            <div class="button"><input id="table1"type="radio" name="table_selector" checked="checked"> <label for="table1">1</label></div>
            <div class="button"><input id="table2"type="radio" name="table_selector"> <label for="table2">2</label></div>
            <div class="button"><input id="table3"type="radio" name="table_selector"> <label for="table3">3</label></div>
            <div class="button"><input id="table4"type="radio" name="table_selector"> <label for="table4">4</label></div>
            <div class="button"><input id="table5"type="radio" name="table_selector"> <label for="table5">5</label></div>
            <div class="button"><input id="table6"type="radio" name="table_selector"> <label for="table6">6</label></div>
            <div class="button"><input id="table7"type="radio" name="table_selector"> <label for="table7">7</label></div>
            <div class="button"><input id="table8"type="radio" name="table_selector"> <label for="table8">8</label></div>
            <div class="button"><input id="table9"type="radio" name="table_selector"> <label for="table9">9</label></div>
            <div class="button"><input id="table10"type="radio" name="table_selector"> <label for="table10">10</label></div>
            <div class="button"><input id="table11"type="radio" name="table_selector"> <label for="table11">11</label></div>
            <div class="button"><input id="table12"type="radio" name="table_selector"> <label for="table12">12</label></div>
        </div>
        <div id="search_container" class="content">
            <!--Contents should be generated by PHP-->
            <div id="table1_content">CONTENT1</div>
            <div id="table2_content">CONTENT2</div>
            <div id="table3_content">CONTENT3</div>
            <div id="table4_content">CONTENT4</div>
            <div id="table5_content">CONTENT5</div>
            <div id="table6_content">CONTENT6</div>
            <div id="table7_content">CONTENT7</div>
            <div id="table8_content">CONTENT8</div>
            <div id="table9_content">CONTENT9</div>
            <div id="table10_content">CONTENT10</div>
            <div id="table11_content">CONTENT11</div>
            <div id="table12_content">CONTENT12</div>
        </div>
```

What I want is to select the content (ie those with table#_content id), if and only if the corresponding radio button input is checked (with the id table#).

Unfortunately, the way I've written the code, the radio buttons are buried under two divs (the first one of class "button" and the second of id "button-container") which is then a sibling to the next div (class "content") which only then contains the content I want accessed.

Since there are no parent selectors in CSS, I've been trying to mess with it and see if I can make it happen, but it looks impossible.

Is there any way that I can access this using some CSS trick? I'd prefer to not remove the divs since I'm using them very heavily to make my layout look a certain way.

The end goal is basically to create a tab effect, so if I select a radio button, the content shows up and all the other divs are set to opacity 0. I think this is possible in JavaScript, but I can't code that yet. Also, I read somewhere it's not good to rely on JavaScript for functionality since it can be disabled.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's what the code looks like with all of the html and the CSS applied. You can hover over the tabs and they'll change color. The goal is now to make content appear when the tabs are selected.

[image]

Comment: can you give a rough image of what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use any JavaScript it won't be possible without reorganizing your HTML structure. That [example](http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/) can help you.

Comment: Thanks! It's sad that I have to reorganize. I'm OK with using JavaScript, I guess I'll have to pick up a JS tutorial.

Comment: Happy to help. I would suggest you to look at jQuery.  If you feel this was a good answer, could you mark it as accepted, pelase?